Point Spread Function and Circle-of-Confusion
I have a renderer and am trying to incorporate realistic distortions to it.
My understanding:

Point Spread Function (PSF): For a diffraction limited optical system, the PSF describes how light from an in-focus point source would be spread across a sensor via diffraction.  When dealing with a more complex image (such as a ray-traced scene of extended objects that are all in-focus), you could then simply convolve the PSF with the image.

Circle of Confusion: For a circular aperture, a point source would be spread across the sensor because all of the light rays are not focused perfectly onto a point, and are instead spread out.  This disc is the "circle of confusion".  If the aperture is non-circular, the disc would take on the shape of the aperture and so not necessarily be a perfect circle.


My confusion is, say I wanted to simulate an image of a star that is out of focus.  A reasonable algorithm would seemingly be:

Project the star through the camera model (easy)
Compute the circle-of-confusion as a disc on the sensor, and divide the received irradiance across the circle (I'd probably start uniformly, though I understand it could follow some other distribution across the circle)
Convolve the resulting image with a PSF.

My problem is, the PSF seems to only be applicable when things are in-focus.  In this scenario, things are out of focus.  Does this simply mean there is a separate PSF for each configuration of the optical system, regardless of if it is in focus or not?  I understand that the edges of the circle-of-confusion should be soft due to diffraction, but it isn't obvious to me exactly how that should be modelled.
Ultimately, I don't need something that is 100% accurate, but I'd like something that is qualitatively realistic, at least for the purposes of testing image processing algorithms.

How are you with mathematics? It is better to express this in terms of mathematics.

If there is a moderate amount of defocus, then geometric ray tracing will provide a good approximation to the spot. You don't need to do a point spread function calculation.  Also, the defocus spot will not take on the shape of the aperture. For example, an astigmatic lens function would give asymmetric spots, even if the pupil of the lens is round.
